# Type RowDefinitions not found in xmlns="http://xamarin.com/schemas/2014/forms

Tags: c#, android, xamarin

I am trying to make an app, like tinder.

I wanted to have Text on top of the screen and two buttons for like and dislike, for this I chose to use the gridlayout, that xamarin can use.

Whenever I try to run my app it gives me this error: "Xamarin.Forms.Xaml.XamlParseExeption 7:8: Type RowDefinitions not found in xmlns http://xamarin.com/schemas/2014/forms"

My code is this

```html
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8" ?>
<ContentPage xmlns="http://xamarin.com/schemas/2014/forms"
             xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2009/xaml"
             x:Class="App2.Page1">
  <Grid x:Name="controlGrid" rowSpacing="1" columnSpacing="1">
    <Grid.RowDefinitions>
      <RowDefinitions Height="*"/>
      <RowDefinitions Height="*"/>
      <RowDefinitions Height="*"/>
      <RowDefinitions Height="*"/>
      <RowDefinitions Height="*"/>
    </Grid.RowDefinitions>
    <Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
      <ColumnDefinitions Width="*"/>
      <ColumnDefinitions Width="*"/>
      <ColumnDefinitions Width="*"/>
    </Grid.ColumnDefinitions>

    <Label Text="Slagelse Kommune" Grid.Row="0" Grid.Column="1"/>

    <Button Text="Syntes ikke godt om" Clicked="handle_dislike"
            Grid.Row="2"
            Grid.Column="2"/>

    <Button Text="Syntes godt om" Clicked="handle_like"
            Grid.Row="2"
            Grid.Column="0"/>
  </Grid>

</ContentPage>
```

I've looked in the reference manual, and it had an example on what it should look like, and its pretty much THIS!

I would greatly appreciate any help.

sincerely Me

Answer (score 4, accepted):

`RowDefinition` and `ColumnDefinition` are singular, not plural.

Comment: Thanks, that fixed it!